# Send POST data and open remote form filled with post data

Tags: php, forms

Is there a way to prepare form data in php on one server, and then open and fill that data in form that lies on another server?

So, I have mypreparation.php on SERVER/DOMAIN1, where I prepare data. On SERVER/DOMAIN2 is form.php that can read POST variables and prefill them in input and textarea tags, if POST vars are set.

How can I prepare and send POST data from mypreparation.php (SERVER1), and get page form.php (SERVER2) opened in my browser, with filled data from mypreparation.php?

From user perspective, flow looks like this. User is on DOMAIN1, where she has a link. When she clicks the link, php prepares data and opens form on DOMAIN2 with filled data, waiting for user to click Send. Data can't be sent with GET because it's larger.

This is to be done without javascript, just php1 to php2 which creates html. I control both mypreparation.php and form.php. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the flow, does the user ever enter `DOMAIN1` or does the user only interact with `DOMAIN2`?

Comment: User is on DOMAIN1, and on DOMAIN1 she has a link. When she clicks the link, php prepares data and opens form on DOMAIN2, with filled data.

Comment: Anybody? Php1 from DOMAIN1 sends post data to php2 on DOMAIN2 and php2 opens in user browser with prefilled data. Is it possible?

Comment: I will update my answer.

Comment: @Digital Chris: Ok, as I researched in the meantime I saw that your final solution is right solution. But, it's not as straight forward as I wanted. So I'll do it with ajax invisible form, as originaly planned. Thank you anyway for your time and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion, it seems you want to use server-to-server communication. This can be accomplished with cURL.  PHP in Server1 will serve a page to the user with a link in the format:

```
https://www.server2.com/someurl.php?secretkey=12341234
```

At the same time, server1 will submit a cURL post to server2 with data:

```
secretkey=12341234
otherdata=something
moredata=somethingelse
```

Server2 will save the form data and a request to its someurl.php will use the secretkey to load the data and build a form for the user.

Comment: User doesn't have form, just link. It's ajax function, so I was wondering if when I call mypreparation.php I wouldn't have to dynamicaly create invisible form and trigger submit, but to handle it within php and redirect user to prefilled form

Comment: The question says "This is to be done without javascript" and now you say "It's ajax function".  Suddenly I have a feeling you don't know what you're talking about at all.

Comment: Listen, user has a link. When she clicks a link it calls php file via ajax. That's the end of javascript. From there on, my question is if all can be done within php.

Comment: Provide the code.  What does the ajax do?  Why not just have ajax get the data and submit to server 2?

Comment: I know that I can get back to ajax, create invisible form and trigger submit. My question here is can it be done without javascript, just php to php. Javascript/ajax in this question is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes it can be done the way I showed you above. It looks like a link but is a form submit with hidden fields.

Comment: That's html to php, I am searching for php to php solution.

Comment: Server to server communication? Yes you could also do that. But you already have the user clicking the link right? Why not submit it that way?  If you want to, you can have Server1 make a cURL submit with all data to server 2, possibly with a secret key. Then the user clicks the link like server2.com/url.php?secretkey=$secretKey . This way server2 can recognize who the user is.

Comment: Ok, as I researched in the meantime I saw that your final solution is right solution. But, it's not as straight forward as I wanted. So I'll do it with ajax invisible form, as originaly planned. Thank you anyway for your time and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

The link: `http://www.whatever.com?var1=123&var2=456&....`

In Domain 2 you can extract this data with GET['var1'], GET['var2'], ...
And echo it in the form fields.

Example

```
<form>
  <input type = "text" value = "<?php echo GET['var1']; ?>">
</form>
```

Cheers

Comment: I can't use GET variables, because prepared data is larger and goes into textarea tag. For example, prepared email text can't fit in GET